# TypeScript Define Single Type for Union Types

Tags: typescript, types, union-types

In my TypeScript I have many methods like this and in any method witch have the same parameter or return type I should repeat these union types:

```
foo(bar: 'a' | 'b' | 'z' | 'AA'){
}
```

Is there any way to define a single type for these union types and didn't repeat these codes any time (without using enum or passing parameters as any)?

Comment: `type Example = 'a' | 'b' | 'z' | 'AA'`, used like `foo(bar: Example){}`

Comment: Thank you very much @NicholasTower this is exactly what I want.